# What is the right way of doing Client and Server communicate with Sockets in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I've seen many people talk about this any many people have criticised my attempt at doing this and said that I am not following the official rule of "What to send, who sends it, and how the other side responds." Is there even a rule for this? I'm not sure anymore...

Here is my current setup of communication.

- Server: Gets alerted a new client has connected.
- Server: Asks the client for the socket password.
- Client: Sends a packet with the socket password.
- Server: Okay, now give me some information on your device.
- Client: Sends a packet including the device information
- Server:
  Okay, we've added you to the dictionary, thanks.

Now, if I tell the server to ask the client for the socket password straight away, what if the client hasn't called BeginReceive yet? What do I do about this?

I guess this question is answering my worries of the fact that I'm doing it wrong or I'm doing something wrong, how should I be doing this?

Who goes first? I've been told the client should only communicate with the server and the server should "respond" not "ask". Am I breaking any rules here?

Comment: If it were up to me - I would design it the way where Client Always Requests. Server just Responds. Which is inline with: Last statement in your question.

Comment: Welcome good sir.  I'm not sure if this sort of question is best for SO. [ask].   Perhaps another site on the Stack Exchange network?  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @PrateekShrivastava, so something like this?

Client: Sends a packet with the socket password.
Server: (if password was wrong) Sends a packet saying password was wrong 
Client: (if sent wrong password) re-sends the socket password packet.
Client: Sends device information 
Server: Sends authentication complete packet

Comment: That seems simple enough, only one concern here (may be for later) - Assume someone poses as the Server. So a legit client connects to it and sends the socket password. Malicious Server - now knows your password. Later some time - you may need to think & implement security here.

Comment: Server side app should generate a Key Pair and share Clients Private Key to them beforehand (via legit channel). Key Pairs should be per client. Now all requests from Client - can have a Client Id and rest of the message body should be encrypted using its Private Key. Server should pick the Clients PublicKey and decrypt message body and process further.

Comment: I second Prateek Shrivastava's comment. I also don't see a reason to work in such a low level as sockets, when you have WCF, or HTTPWebRequest. What you described can be solved simply by using HTTP as the transfer protocol, limiting you to a request-response model (but you don't seem to need more anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Seegal. Ideally, you'd want to minimize the amount of calls the server is pinging down to the client. The server machine is your powerhouse, and if you're performing intensive work on a potato client PC, you may run into issues. Because you can't just tell people to upgrade their machines to use your service, that's on you.

The method I would use to hand up data would be a packet consisting of bitwise flags that will allow you to package multiple packet cases together without significant issue.

E.G.

```
[Flags]
enum NETWORK_CODES
{
    CLIENT_CONNECT = 1 << 0,
    CLIENT_DISCONNECT = 1 << 1,
    CLIENT_PERFORM_ACTION = 1 << 2
}
```

This way, you can check for multiple flags at once and handle it accordingly.

```
if(packetFlags = CLIENT_CONNECT & CLIENT_PERFORM_ACTION) then
    Authenticate(packetClient);
    PerformAction();
end //Pseudo; don't hate. :D
```

It's a scalable solution, which is ideal for networking. If it doesn't scale, then you're in a bad spot and have to redo a whole bunch of code.

The server doesn't need to know if a client is there unless it's an active connection, which cuts back even further the amount of work you actually have to do.

[image: A simple diagram for a pseudo server authentication system.]

Comment: Another thing to note about password security, try to hash and salt the outgoing passwords. That way the client puts in cleartext and the server has to decrypt and check. So nobody and their grandma with wireshark can just get all your passwords and usernames. :)

Comment: "Potato Client" -- Good one. But potato is my favorite food. I'll never look at it the same way again now.

Comment: What is a potato client?

Comment: This was in reference to the strength of a machine. If they have a potato they are a potato client, so you need to make sure any potato clients that will be using your service are welcomed by your superior cabbage technology.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any universal rules. Design your protocol according to your needs, and then you have rules. A socket is a peer to peer communication system (once the connection is established, in the case of TCP), which means that either peer may send any data at any time. It's purely up to the protocol engineer to design what can be sent, by whom, when, and how.

Think about Secure Sockets. SSL uses a protocol that allows the two peers to send and receive data through a secure channel however they wish, just like the underlying socket allows. On the other hand, think about HTTP. HTTP is purely a request/response oriented protocol. As such, it's far more restrictive than a protocol such as SSL, but it works perfectly well for the use cases it was designed for, along with many more, due to its inherent flexibility at the message level.

To answer the question "who goes first?", you can think of the act of connecting to the server as "going first". You can also think of the act of the server accepting the connection as "going second". So, that puts you back at square one; design your protocol however you see fit. Some protocols involve the server sending some sort of "welcome" message upon accepting the request, and some don't (HTTP, for example); either way is fine. In your case, it might make sense for the server to send a welcome message which contains some flags describing what is required to proceed, such as a password. The client would connect, consume the welcome message, and then proceed as appropriate.

To answer the question regarding whether or not the client has started reading from the socket, it isn't relevant. The server can send data immediately upon accepting the connection; the data will be buffered until the client application reads it by issuing read requests sufficient to consume it.

This is all more open-ended than is really appropriate for SO, but hopefully it helps.